# aspx page open a hyperlink via a button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I've read a few answers, and tried a bit of different code from them, but haven't been able to solve this. I am a newbie at this and it seems like quite  a simple thing to do, apologies if the answer is really obvious, just need it to work really..
So far, I have an aspx page in Visual Studio 2010 / it was created by someone else, and has both JavaScript and cSharp code behind it.
What I would like to happen is that, an 'Edit' button appears on the page in a table in the correct place, and as a result of pressing it, another page is called allowing the editing (of contacts - it's an internal website).

I can get the link working OK as a 'normal' hyperlink, using this line of code:

```
    var editcontact = '<td align = "right" colspan = "40" class = 
"contactBorder"><a href="WebForm1.aspx?supplier_id=' + 
dataRow.supplier_id + '">Open Contact(s) For Edit</a></td>';
```

edit contact then gets put in a table like structure (maybe it's "form" given the HTML tags):

```
finishedcontacts += openrow + contactid + contactname + 
contactjobtitle + contactlocation + contacttelephone + 
contactemail+ editcontact + '</form></tr>';
```

That's OK but it's not very 'nice', what I would like is an actual edit button, I can get the button to appear, but the last time I tried it pressing it does nothing:

```
var editcontact = '<asp:button id = "editImage4" runat="server" 
Text="Click me" 
OnClientClick="window.open(\'WebForm1.aspx\\?supplier_id=\' + dataRow.supplier_id + \', \'WebForm1\');" />';
```

Any ideas on how to get this working OK from a button?

Here is some other code I tried, which was to separate out the generation of the url from the calling code, but none of them seemed to work:

```
//var url = string.Format("{0}?supplier_id={1}", "../WebForm1.aspx", dataRow.supplier_id);
//var url = string.Format("{0}?supplier_id={1}", @"../WebForm1.aspx", dataRow.supplier_id);
//var url = 'string.Format("{0} supplier_id={1}", "WebForm1.aspx",'+ dataRow.supplier_id +')';
var url = 'WebForm1.aspx?supplier_id= '+ dataRow.supplier_id +'';
var supplierid1 = dataRow.supplier_id;
```

Any ideas what be greatly appreciated. This is my first ever post..

Comment: Does it work with a hyperlink other than just not looking exactly how you want it to look?   If so, use css to style the link or replace the text with an `img`.

Comment: Yeah, it does work how I want with this code:

var editcontact = '<td align = "right" colspan = "40" class = 
"contactBorder"><a href="WebForm1.aspx?supplier_id=' + 
dataRow.supplier_id + '">Open Contact(s) For Edit</a></td>'; 
Happy to try this but not sure how: "If so, use css to style "

Answer (score 0):

Use Response.Redirect(url) if you want to redirect using your button and this button must be a server side control.

Comment: So that gave: var editcontact = '<asp:button id = "editImage4" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="Reponse.Redirect(\'WebForm1.aspx\\?supplier_id=\' + dataRow.supplier_id + \', \'WebForm1\');" />';
Clicking the button continued to do nothing..

Comment: Write your code in the button click event on the server side .

Comment: Your code would be Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?supplier_id="+dataRow.supplier_id)

Comment: I think the trouble is, the button doesn't 'exist' without the code I supplied; it's 'generating' the button. 
I tried adding a button to the page separately, it would be loads easier if I could do this, but it keeps giving an error like 'Inserting an ASP.NET control will covert the HTML form in the page to an ASP.NET form and remove all it's current properties' Do you want to insert the ASP.NET control?
If you press yes, it breaks the whole website..and I think this means I can't do what you are suggesting (for instance, I can't see the button in Design view, so I can't go to it's 'onClick'

Comment: if your URL is correct then this should work

modify your button like this

 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" />
then in the head section of the html code  :     
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

        function Button1_onclick() {
            window.open(\'WebForm1.aspx\\?supplier_id=\' + dataRow.supplier_id + \', \'WebForm1\')
        }

// ]]>
    </script>

Comment: i tried to paste your url in the window.open() method but it seems the string is not properly constructed so it is not getting accepted and the .net IntelliSense returns an error.

Comment: Edit contact set to: var editContact = '<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="return Button2_onclick()" />', then added this in the head, lets get my URL out of there: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[function Button2_onclick() { window.open("http://www.w3schools.com"); } // ]]> </script> This is in the head1 bit of the HTML. Result: nothing happens still when pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, a colleague helped me out with this.
As other posters identified there was some problems with the URL, and especially with the escapes.
Anyway below is the code in the unlikely event anyone needs something similar.

buttoncode = '';

var editcontact = '' + buttoncode + '';

And we added a function (which should probably be called a method or whatever):
   function OpenContactForEdit(supplier_id)
    {
    window.location = "WebForm1.aspx?supplier_id=" + supplier_id;
    }

Comments:
This bit is very important:
onClick="OpenContactForEdit(\'' + dataRow.supplier_id + '\')"

Note exactly how we needed to escape (and 'end escape') the single quotes.
I believe that was quite a big part of why, what I was doing was not working.